# R, how to do anova in a loop over dataframe?

Tags: r, anova

I would like to do 2ways anova, and store the p value and than do tukey hsd, but i have a problem with the initial table. Not always I have full data, so not always it is possible to perfors anova, I dont know how to do this so my script runs, than skip the not full data and runns further. my data looks like this:

https://filebin.net/w5cfuwztae7yk747

in the link there is example with two Accessions, but in real data there is 3013 accessions and some of them dont have all light conditions or all  genotypes

```
67822  AT2G41680        f      HL_f_Dejan58 1.240108e+06    HL      AT2G41680 f
 70136  AT2G41680        f     HL_f_Dejan_61 3.384010e+06    HL    AT2G41680 f
 72450  AT2G41680     ntrc HL_ntrc_ Dejan_62 1.410768e+05    HL AT2G41680 ntrc
 74764  AT2G41680     ntrc  HL_ntrc_Dejan_66 5.642197e+00    HL AT2G41680 ntrc
77078  AT2G41680     ntrc   HL_ntrc_Dejan65 3.921952e+05    HL AT2G41680 ntrc
 78997  AT2G41680       WT    LL_WT_Dejan_41 1.016001e+07    LL   AT2G41680 WT
 81433  AT2G41680       WT    LL_WT_Dejan_43 9.320892e+06    LL   AT2G41680 WT
 83869  AT2G41680       WT    LL_WT_Dejan_49 8.560308e+06    LL   AT2G41680 WT
```

there is 4 genotypes, and four light conditions 
I am trying to do something like this:

```
AOV<- data.frame()
IDs<- unique(Dejan_all_new_norm$Accession)
for (i in 1 : length(IDs)){
 temp<-Dejan_all_new_norm[(Dejan_all_new_norm$Accession)==IDs[i],]
    aov2<-aov(value ~ genotype + Light + genotype:Light, data = temp)
    AOV <- rbind(as.character(unique(IDs[i])),aov2,AOV)
}
```

so i want to subset each gene (Accession) and than do ANOVA, but after this  i want do tukey to have something like this:

```
$`genotype:Light`
                    diff       lwr        upr     p adj
m:FL-f:FL        -7324259.81 -16715470  2066950.5 0.3486778
ntrc:FL-f:FL      1662873.54  -7728337 11054083.9 0.9999998
WT:FL-f:FL       -5219263.59 -13913835  3475307.7 0.7927417
f:HL-f:FL        -4936680.12 -13871535  3998174.3 0.8796738
m:HL-f:FL        -7389937.49 -16324792  1544916.9 0.2496858
ntrc:HL-f:FL     -7122962.46 -16057817  1811891.9 0.3102106
```

I would like to work on this simple loop that is my example, because it seems easiest way.
I will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

read_csv(file = "https://filebin.net/w5cfuwztae7yk747/two.csv") %>%
  group_by(Accession) %>%
  do(broom::tidy(TukeyHSD(aov(value ~ genotype + Light + genotype:Light, data = .)))) %>%
  ungroup
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 264 x 7
   Accession     term comparison    estimate   conf.low  conf.high  adj.p.value
   <chr>   <fctr>      <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 AT2G41680 genotype        m-f -1586182.59 -3616647.7   444282.5 1.708496e-01
 2 AT2G41680 genotype     ntrc-f -5705550.95 -7694992.3 -3716109.6 2.609223e-08
 3 AT2G41680 genotype       WT-f -1568375.95 -3557817.3   421065.4 1.647950e-01
 4 AT2G41680 genotype     ntrc-m -4119368.37 -6149833.5 -2088903.3 2.214399e-05
 5 AT2G41680 genotype       WT-m    17806.64 -2012658.5  2048271.8 9.999951e-01
 6 AT2G41680 genotype    WT-ntrc  4137175.00  2147733.6  6126616.4 1.464605e-05
 7 AT2G41680    Light      HL-FL -3854435.85 -5849789.4 -1859082.3 4.872013e-05
 8 AT2G41680    Light      LL-FL  1528123.46  -467230.1  3523477.0 1.844033e-01
 9 AT2G41680    Light      ML-FL -2821752.94 -4775345.6  -868160.3 2.283331e-03
10 AT2G41680    Light      LL-HL  5382559.31  3311883.1  7453235.6 2.176770e-07
# ... with 254 more rows
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I think I don't exactly know how to use the code you've provided...  Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
In addition: Warning message:
Missing column names filled in: 'X1' [1] cold you maybe provide some explaination how to use it with a df not read file?

Comment: Is it possible that one of your covariates (genotype or light) only has a single level for some accession in your original data? If yes, would it be possible to exclude this accession from the analysis? Otherwise, you would have to use a custom formula for each accession based on the availability of the data.

Comment: yes, i tried to explain this in the question that sometimes there was no measurement for light or genotype, but there is 3013, removing by hand is not an option. Thans why i thought that a loop with some if{} statment will do. but i dont know how to loop and get the table for anowa and than put it to simmilar loop for tukey. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set that reflects this?

Comment: thank you very much, i uploaded a file with the two examples as before and two incomplete in ligh conditions, but in the data in migh be also genotype missing but i couldn't now find a good example                     https://filebin.net/xktdf5i8568u3svi

Comment: The new file runs on my system without error. What is your error message with the new test data?

Comment: hmmmmmmmm I have example that gives this error but it's https://filebin.net/v4v18gihfuz2pq80 but it is 100 first rows that dont cover a full gene, when i pick some genes by hand and remove a genotype by hand it also runs in your code https://filebin.net/hr5wy12jzi43t4uy the eroor i get when I run full data Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
In addition: Warning message:
Missing column names filled in: 'X1' [1]  I simply dont get it. I want to put it in a loop so i can see on which gene it stop

Comment: IDs<- unique(Dejan_all_new_norm$Accession)
for (i in 1 : length(IDs)){
  temp<-Dejan_all_new_norm[(Dejan_all_new_norm$Accession)==IDs[i],]
  AOV <- do(broom::tidy(TukeyHSD(aov(value ~ genotype + Light + genotype:Light, data = temp))))
  }                would be something like this possible?

Comment: Try determining how many distinct values for genotype and light there are for each Accession: `read_csv(file = "https://filebin.net/hr5wy12jzi43t4uy/FOUR2.csv") %>%
  group_by(Accession) %>%
  summarize(n_genotype = length(unique(genotype)), 
            n_Light = length(unique(Light)))`

Comment: I subset only these that have more than one light condition and it worked. Thanks a lot!