# One way anova in a loop

Tags: r, loops, anova

I'm trying to do an one-way ANOVA using the size condition in a loop for each Compound.Name and then a TuckeyHSD and store the pvalue result in new dataframe for each permutation of the TuckeyHSD for each compound.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47656781/r-how-to-do-anova-in-a-loop-over-dataframe#comment82305270_47657646) has almost what I need but its data is a crosstab table and mine is tabular, haven't been able to make it work with my data.

Could you point me in the right direction to solve this issue ?

EDIT : I've managed to almost make this worked :

```
read.csv(file = 'test-mev-query-size.csv', header = T) 
%>% group_by(Compound.Name) 
%>% do(broom::tidy(TukeyHSD(aov(Measured.Area ~ size, data = .)))) 
%>% ungroup
```

And I get the same error as the guy from the other post,

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

So I've tried to manage this issue and by mistake I've replace `data =.`  by `data = GC`

`GC` being

```
GC <- read.csv(file = 'test-mev-query-size.csv', header = T)
```

And now I get this result :

```
Compound.Name                                                         term  contrast null.value   estimate    conf.low  conf.high adj.p.value
   <chr>                                                                 <chr> <chr>         <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 (3-Hydroxy-4-methoxyphenyl)ethylene glycol tris(trimethylsilyl) ether size  M-L               0   -814155. -146910662. 145282352.       1.00 
 2 (3-Hydroxy-4-methoxyphenyl)ethylene glycol tris(trimethylsilyl) ether size  p-L               0  -4956448. -207938755. 198025860.       1.00 
 3 (3-Hydroxy-4-methoxyphenyl)ethylene glycol tris(trimethylsilyl) ether size  S-L               0 -40549091. -186767739. 105669556.       0.892
 4 (3-Hydroxy-4-methoxyphenyl)ethylene glycol tris(trimethylsilyl) ether size  p-M               0  -4142293. -207930562. 199645976.       1.00 
 5 (3-Hydroxy-4-methoxyphenyl)ethylene glycol tris(trimethylsilyl) ether size  S-M               0 -39734936. -187070384. 107600511.       0.900
 6 (3-Hydroxy-4-methoxyphenyl)ethylene glycol tris(trimethylsilyl) ether size  S-p               0 -35592644. -239468493. 168283206.       0.970
 7 ?-Alanine, 3TMS derivative                                            size  M-L               0   -814155. -146910662. 145282352.       1.00 
 8 ?-Alanine, 3TMS derivative                                            size  p-L               0  -4956448. -207938755. 198025860.       1.00 
 9 ?-Alanine, 3TMS derivative                                            size  S-L               0 -40549091. -186767739. 105669556.       0.892
10 ?-Alanine, 3TMS derivative                                            size  p-M               0  -4142293. -207930562. 199645976.       1.00
```

But the pvalues are the same repeating over and over regardless of the compound name.

I'm a bit lost, maybe the NA is the dataset are messing things up ?

Anything could help,

Cheers,
Arzock

**Orignal dataset exemple :**

```
 Compound.Name                                  Measured.Area Name size
11                   ?-Alanine, 3TMS derivative       8465634   L1    L
12                   ?-Alanine, 3TMS derivative       7154676   L2    L
13                   ?-Alanine, 3TMS derivative       7168933   L3    L
14                   ?-Alanine, 3TMS derivative       6297177   M1    M
15                   ?-Alanine, 3TMS derivative       6868877   M2    M
16                   ?-Alanine, 3TMS derivative       4506282   M3    M
17                   ?-Alanine, 3TMS derivative       6789789 pool    p
18                   ?-Alanine, 3TMS derivative       4034506   S1    S
19                   ?-Alanine, 3TMS derivative       9004868   S2    S
20                   ?-Alanine, 3TMS derivative       5873538   S3    S
21                 ?-D-Lactose, 8TMS derivative      35787723   L1    L
22                 ?-D-Lactose, 8TMS derivative      46760086   L2    L
23                 ?-D-Lactose, 8TMS derivative      64378939   L3    L
24                 ?-D-Lactose, 8TMS derivative      40796759   M1    M
25                 ?-D-Lactose, 8TMS derivative      50012840   M2    M
26                 ?-D-Lactose, 8TMS derivative      31132791   M3    M
27                 ?-D-Lactose, 8TMS derivative      80753261 pool    p
28                 ?-D-Lactose, 8TMS derivative     104465007   S1    S
29                 ?-D-Lactose, 8TMS derivative      41617794   S2    S
30                 ?-D-Lactose, 8TMS derivative      49398047   S3    S
51 1-Methyladenosine,tris(trimethylsilyl) ether     277710179   L1    L
52 1-Methyladenosine,tris(trimethylsilyl) ether     351095300   L2    L
53 1-Methyladenosine,tris(trimethylsilyl) ether     173003628   L3    L
54 1-Methyladenosine,tris(trimethylsilyl) ether     267239831   M1    M
55 1-Methyladenosine,tris(trimethylsilyl) ether     230375478   M2    M
56 1-Methyladenosine,tris(trimethylsilyl) ether     177557679   M3    M
57 1-Methyladenosine,tris(trimethylsilyl) ether     268424161 pool    p
58 1-Methyladenosine,tris(trimethylsilyl) ether     142731061   S1    S
59 1-Methyladenosine,tris(trimethylsilyl) ether     276833806   S2    S
60 1-Methyladenosine,tris(trimethylsilyl) ether     260643543   S3    S
```